# LXDE, Mint, Ubuntu MATE - Same installation error

Tags: system-installation, python, ubuntu-mate

So, I've tried to install all of the operating systems mentioned in the title and ALL of them give me the same exact error, which comes from

```
"/usr/lib/python3.5/codecs.py", line 321:
"UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x91 in position 269: invalid start byte"
```

Interestingly enough, it doesn't happen in Manjaro. How do I fix it so I can install Ubuntu MATE?

I can't find anything anywhere about this. All I know is that it's a python bug, but when it comes to happening during a Linux installation, I seem to be the only one on the whole internet that it happens to.

I've been fighting this for the past 5 days and I can't seem to make it install. I boot and run it without issues, but once the language is selected (English) and I click "Continue", I'm presented with the mentioned error.

For the love of God, someone help! Otherwise I'll just throw the darn laptop away (literally) and I'd rather not do that since I bought it last Wednesday (InnJoo Leapbook M100 (same as A100)).

Also, contacting the manufacturer or the people that sold it to me is out of the question. I already did that, they're useless.

Comment: In what language is it now?

Comment: Which version of Ubuntu MATE? Did you check with md5sum, that the download was good, that md5sum matches the listed string? How did you create the boot drive? DVD disk or USB pendrive or memory card? Which tool did you use? Does the live system work (when running from the installation media in English (the standard language))?

Comment: @George It's in English.

Comment: @sudodus Ubuntu Mate 16.04.2 LTS 64bit - The download is good. - I used Rufus to create a bootable USB. - The live system works as it should.

Comment: If the live system works correctly, I would suspect that there is some problem with a driver, for example for the graphics chip or wifi chip. Please check the brand name and model or the graphics chip or wifi chip, and let us know. Check when booted live. Maybe the installed system will work with some boot option(s), for example `nomodeset`. See this link and links from it, http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2230389&p=13370808#post13370808 . Maybe you need a proprietary driver for graphics or wifi.

Comment: @sudodus If it's a driver issue, I suspect it's a Wi-Fi problem since it doesn't work (doesn't even detect it as an existing hardware component) unless I install the driver manually. I'll see what I can do and come back. It might take a while since I don't really know much about Linux.

Comment: I am not an expert on wifi, but there are several people at AskUbuntu, who are. Let us hope some of them will see your question. Otherwise you might modify the title of your question in order to attract the wifi experts.

Comment: When do you get this message ? Is this just a warning or is there a problem that needs to be fixed or worked around ? This is a python error and more likely then not you will need to file a bug report, but it is completely unclear how the codecs.py is being used or how this affects you.

Comment: @bodhi.zazen I boot up the Ubuntu. I double click Install. I leave the selected language to English. I click Continue. The error pops up. - Also, this python error's been known for a while, it's just that it only seems to happen to me on a Linux installation. Most of the other cases I've seen are people just compiling and writing their own code.

Comment: If you can not install because of the error, first check the integrity of the iso -  https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuHashes . If the sum is OK you have to file a bug report against the iso.

Comment: Did you fix this? I have the same laptop. I dunno how to go about it @DoombringerBG

Comment: @Jason I honestly don't remember much. I think it either had to do with the USB or with the software I used to install the OS onto it. If I remember correctly, I think I gave up with the Ubuntu and went with Kubuntu or Kali Linux. Though, these days I'd recommend PopOS (installed on the USB using Balena Etcher). P.S. If you can, return the laptop and get different one (avoid anything from that company as well), it's absolute garbage. Something I found the hard way.

Comment: Thanks @DoombringerBG. You were helpful